# How to convert encoding of FTP Getlisting array of strings?

Tags: vb.net, encoding, ssis, ftp-client

I am using the following vb code to get the list of files in a ftp directory and populate a database table with it to be used in another integration process. Please forgive my bad bad programming skills (I am not a vb.net developer).

```
Public Sub Main()

    Dim StrFolderArrary As String() = Nothing
    Dim StrFileArray As String() = Nothing
    Dim fileName As String
    Dim RemotePath As String

    RemotePath = Dts.Variables("User::FTPFullPath").Value.ToString()

    Dim ADODBConnection As SqlClient.SqlConnection
    ADODBConnection = DirectCast(Dts.Connections("DB_Connection").AcquireConnection(Dts.Transaction), SqlClient.SqlConnection)
    Dim cm As ConnectionManager = Dts.Connections("FTP_Connection") 'FTP connection manager name
    Dim ftp As FtpClientConnection = New FtpClientConnection(cm.AcquireConnection(Nothing))

    ftp.Connect() 'Connecting to FTP Server

    ftp.SetWorkingDirectory(RemotePath) 'Provide the Directory on which you are working on FTP Server
    ftp.GetListing(StrFolderArrary, StrFileArray) 'Get all the files and Folders List


    'If there is no file in the folder, strFile Arry will contain nothing, so close the connection.
    If StrFileArray Is Nothing Then
        ftp.Close()

        'If Files are there, Loop through the StrFileArray arrary and insert into table
    Else
        For Each fileName In StrFileArray
            'MessageBox.Show(fileName)
            Dim SQLCommandText As String
            SQLCommandText = "INSERT INTO dbo._FTPFileList ([DirName],[FileName]) VALUES (N'" + RemotePath + "', N'" + fileName + "')"
            'MessageBox.Show(SQLCommandText)
            Dim cmdDatabase As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand(SQLCommandText, ADODBConnection)
            cmdDatabase.ExecuteNonQuery()
        Next
        ftp.Close()
    End If
    ' Add your code here
    '
    Dts.TaskResult = ScriptResults.Success
End Sub
```

It works fine and I get the results in the database table. The problem is that the encoding of the strings coming from FTP makes the file names with accentuation to be written incorrectly as shown in the example below.

[database table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0q5Rl.png)

The correct file name is Razão and I know that the db collation is correct since it can be written like this.

So I tried to convert the strings using this code for each file name in the string array but without any success.

```
For Each fileName In StrFileArray

    Dim utf8 As UTF8Encoding = New UTF8Encoding(True, True)
    Dim bytes As Byte() = New Byte(utf8.GetByteCount(fileName) + utf8.GetPreamble().Length - 1) {}
    Array.Copy(utf8.GetPreamble(), bytes, utf8.GetPreamble().Length)
    utf8.GetBytes(fileName, 0, fileName.Length, bytes, utf8.GetPreamble().Length)
    Dim fileName2 As String = utf8.GetString(bytes, 0, bytes.Length)
```

I believe it is coming with different encoding from the FTP side so I would like to know how to convert the strings during the GetListing method.

Or do you have any ideas how to deal with this?

Thanks in advance.

edit:
I also tried the following code without success.

```
Dim utf8 As Encoding = Encoding.UTF8
Dim w1252 As Encoding = Encoding.GetEncoding(1252)
Dim w1252Bytes As Byte() = w1252.GetBytes(fileName)
Dim utf8Bytes As Byte() = Encoding.Convert(w1252, utf8, w1252Bytes)
Dim utf8Chars As Char() = New Char(utf8.GetCharCount(utf8Bytes, 0, utf8Bytes.Length) - 1) {}
utf8.GetChars(utf8Bytes, 0, utf8Bytes.Length, utf8Chars, 0)
Dim fileName2 As String = New String(utf8Chars)
```

Comment: What is the `COLLATIONPROPERTY` `LCID` of those fields (`varchar` or `nvarchar`)? If they're set to a Local CodePage (1252, possibly) and the source is `UTF-8`, you need to convert the Encoding. See: [Encoding.Convert](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.encoding.convert).

Comment: @Jimi The collation_name is Latin1_General_CI_AS, the CodePage is 1252 and LCID is 1033. The fields are nvarchar. I tried to convert the Encoding as you mentioned but no success (edited with the code I have used).

Comment: What is `fileName`? Is it the file coming from the FTP server? Shouldn't it be the one UTF-8 encoded? Don't use `utf8.GetCharCount()`. You don't need to count anything. You will need a `MemoryStream` as a Buffer holder and use a  `StreamReader` for the actual conversion. But, have you verified that the file you have transfered is actually UTF-8 encoded and not something else?

Comment: Also, LCID 1033 with CodePage 1252 means En-US base ANSI encoding. If the destination language is standard Spanish, LCID should be 1034. With a `nvarchar` field, you should have Unicode (UTF16-LE). So, I'm not sure what we are reading here.

Comment: fileName is name of the file coming from de FTP Server. All I need is the name in order to use it with another ssis package where it will be downloaded and processed. I don't need the content of the file right now. I believe StreamReader is to read the content, correct me if I am wrong (I am not vb.net dev). If I am wrong, can you provide an example with it please?

Comment: Also, the destination language is Brazilian Portuguese and I am not sure which encoding the file is coming. I believe it is UTF8 but I don't know how to verify. Can you help with that too? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Still missing the main information: the FTP file encoding. Try to read the file without specifying **any** encoding. After you have extracted the text, storing it in some strings **inspect the strings content**. Have the *Latin* characters representation been preserved? Yes? Try to write the string to the destination DB fields. After storing the strings, have the *Latin* characters representation been preserved? No? The you have to encode your string (which are now in Unicode (`UTF16-LE`) format) using the DB fields encoding.

Comment: I put a `MessageBox.Show(fileName)` rigth after the `For Each fileName In StrFileArray` and the Latin characters shown messed up. When I insert the strings in DB, they are messed up as well.

Comment: If the strings coming straight from file you downloaded already do not support Latin chars, then the encoding is not UFT-8. That's the default encoding. The strings would have beed read correctly. Unless, the text is already compromised because a local encoding was used that doesn't support those chars. Can you share that file? I could give it a look and determine the encoding (or determine whether the encoding is already "messed up" or recoverable in some way.

Comment: Hi @Jimi. I can't share the file since it has sensitive data. I can try to mask it and share a replica, but I guess we are missing the point here. I am not interested in the content of the file now, all I need is its name. So I believe the FTP server encoding is the problem. This server is in a third party hosting service outside of our company. I managed to create a VM in Azure with a FTP server and it solved the problem. Since I can't have access to this third party server and my clients will use Latin characters in file names I need to manage this encoding issue.

Comment: I wasn't surely talking about one of the files content, but the FTP server dir listing you're retrieving. Usually, online services encode in UTF-8. If you already tested and ruled out UTF-8 and can't ask what's what, you need to find out. First thing to try is the local encoding (the language of the server OS  is run). But this could imply that the Latin specific characters might be already compromised. If you can't share the dir listing (or part of it), there's no much else I can say without any other informations.